# Do the apparent infinities at the center of black holes disappear if instead a phase-change takes the place of its singularity?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, singularities

When I watch physics documentaries that discuss black holes, they talk of impossible infinities in the singularity at a black hole's centre.

I was wondering about the bubbles of water vapour in boiling water. If you time-reverse such a bubble - and exclude prior knowledge that the bubble actually comes from a phase change of liquid water to water vapour - would you also not come up with a 'singularity' and 'impossible inifinities'?

Wouldn't those issues dispappear if you then admitted that prior knowlege: the time-reversal didn't end with a singularity but with a phase change, water vapour to water?

If it is, does that help with thinking about black holes? That is, there's no singularity but instead there's a phase change back to whatever it is our space-time arises from?

Could that thought also be extended to the big bang? Some quantity of a 4D(?) fluid that went through a phase change resulting in our 4D expanding universe?

These thoughts have been bugging me for a while so I thought I'd come here and ask. I hope the question makes sense!

Comment: You seem to imagine a black hole in terms of Newtonian gravity as a star being squeezed to its center. A General Relativity picture is different. A black hole doesn’t have a center. The Schwarzschild singularity is not a point, but an infinitely long line, which may not even exist, because the spacelike radius of the horizon is already zero, so anything “inside” it is only an unfalsifiable assumption. Furthermore, a singularity has nothing to do with matter. A Schwarzschild black hole contains nothing, but pure vacuum. On the Big Bang, Hawkin’s “Shuttercock” model doesn’t have a singularity.

Comment: You refer to infinities at the singularity, but, even if the singularity exists, no physical infinities arise there. The collapsing matter is torn apart by the tidal forces to elementary particles, each point-like elementary particle hits a separate spot along the infinitely long line of the singularity, and then time stops. No “infinity” issues. On the “curvature infinity” imagine an illustration of drawing progressively smaller circles around a point on a piece of paper. The curvature of the circles approaches infinity at the point. This however causes no issues for paper.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, @safesphere. The documentaries I was referring to obviously dumbed things down for general consumption.